# Why does a prop provided with a static object re-renders the component on change?

Tags: vue.js

I encountered this trivial but head-scratching case that feels uncomfortably counter-intuitive.

Imagine a Vue component that accepts 2 props: one object (`filters`) and one string (`button`). The component will be able to change the `button` prop by emitting an `update:button` event. If the parent is concerned about the changes, it's expected to use the `.sync` modifier.

The child component also has a deep watcher on the object prop (`filters`).

```
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: `<button @click="onClick">{{ button }}</button>`,
  props: { filters: Object, button: String, },

  watch: {
    filters: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        console.log('filters changed')
      },
    },
  },

  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.$emit('update:button',
        Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
      )

      console.log('button clicked')
    },
  },
});

----

new Vue({
  data: {
    filters: {
      search: ''
    },
    button: 'Click me!',
  }
});
```

It seems now that there's an important difference in behavior of the child component, based on the way of defining the `filters` prop in the parent:

```
<!-- Filters prop passed entirely -->
<child-component :filters="filters" :button.sync="button" />


<!-- Filters prop constructed in place -->
<child-component :filters="{ search: filters.search }" :button.sync="button" />
```

In the first scenario: everything works as expected. The `filters` watcher in the child behaves properly, the synced `button` prop behaves properly. But it starts getting weird in the latter scenario: as soon as an update for the `button` prop syncs, the `filters` watcher is triggered as well!

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. Is this expected? If so, why?

Here's a contrived JSFiddle showing this behavior:

https://jsfiddle.net/5eqzbsm4/

Comment: on each render there will be a new filter value with the same content thus: render1 -> :filter="filter1" and render2 -> :filter="filter2" but be reminded filter1 !== filter2 thus the watcher notices a change and triggers

Comment: A deep watch will trigger also when the object instance changes. Note that `{ foo: 'bar' } !== { foo: 'bar' }`, they're two different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is a regular behavior because each time a `button` changes VueJs rerenders `child-component` and thus recreates `{ search: filters.search }` because it's constructed right in the template